# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' while trying to add multiple keras Dense layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The input are 3 independent channels of 1000 features. I'm trying to pass each channel through a independent NN path, then concatenate them into a flat layer. Then apply a FCN on the flatten layer for a binary classification. 
I'm trying to add multiple Dense layers together, like this:

def tst_1():

```
inputs = Input((3, 1000, 1))

dense10 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(inputs[0,:,1])
dense11 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(dense10)
dense12 = Dense(56, activation='relu')(dense11)

dense20 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(inputs[1,:,1])
dense21 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(dense20)
dense22 = Dense(56, activation='relu')(dense21)

dense30 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(inputs[2,:,1])
dense31 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(dense30)
dense32 = Dense(56, activation='relu')(dense31)

flat = keras.layers.Add()([dense12, dense22, dense32])

dense1 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(flat)
drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
dense2 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(drop1)
drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense2)
dense3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(drop2)
densef = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense3)

model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = densef)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
model = tst_1()

model.summary()
```

but I got this error:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
>      1310             ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
>      1311         """
>   -> 1312         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
>      1313 
>      1314         # Prevent cycles.
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Comment: You should add more information: for example what are you trying to accomplish, the nature of the dataset, preprocessing ... The output of model.summaty would also be useful

Comment: The input is 3 independent channels of 1000 observation. I'm trying to pass each channel through a independent NN path, then concatenate them into a flat layer.  Then apply a FCN on the flatten layer for a binary classification.

Comment: Then...  why are you adding instead of concatenating? The size of flat will be very different.

Comment: I applied the concatenate but I got same error. I guess Add() does the same thing here as the input is 1D tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CAta.RAy

I solved it in this way:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense,Dropout, Lambda
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K




def tst_1(): 
    inputs = Input((3, 1000))

    x1 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,0])(inputs)
    dense10 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(x1)
    dense11 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(dense10)
    dense12 = Dense(56, activation='relu')(dense11)

    x2 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,1])(inputs)
    dense20 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(x2)
    dense21 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(dense20)
    dense22 = Dense(56, activation='relu')(dense21)

    x3 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,2])(inputs)
    dense30 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(x3)
    dense31 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(dense30)
    dense32 = Dense(56, activation='relu')(dense31)

    flat = Add()([dense12, dense22, dense32])

    dense1 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(flat)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
    dense2 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(drop1)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense2)
    dense3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(drop2)
    densef = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense3)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = densef)

    return model

Net = tst_1()
Net.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Net.summary()
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that splitting the input data using `inputs[0,:,1]` is not done as a keras layer.

You need to create a [Lambda](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L565) layer to be able to accomplish this.

The following code:

```
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense,Dropout, Lambda, Concatenate
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K


def tst_1(): 

    num_channels = 3
    inputs = Input(shape=(num_channels, 1000, 1))

    branch_outputs = []
    for i in range(num_channels):
        # Slicing the ith channel:
        out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, i, :, :], name = "Lambda_" + str(i))(inputs)

        # Setting up your per-channel layers (replace with actual sub-models):
        out = Dense(224, activation='relu', name = "Dense_224_" + str(i))(out)
        out = Dense(112, activation='relu', name = "Dense_112_" + str(i))(out)
        out = Dense(56, activation='relu', name = "Dense_56_" + str(i))(out)
        branch_outputs.append(out)

    # Concatenating together the per-channel results:
    out = Concatenate()(branch_outputs)


    dense1 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(out)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
    dense2 = Dense(112, activation='relu')(drop1)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense2)
    dense3 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(drop2)
    densef = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense3)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = densef)

    return model

Net = tst_1()
Net.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Net.summary()
```

correctly created the net that you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the output of crop function is (3,1) while it should be (1000,1).

Comment: I got the idea from your answer and solved it in this way:

Comment: @Sam_Ha modified the code to allow the functionality you needed.