# multi-armed bandit agent in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to work through some old tutorials and found it stimulating to keep everything in Keras. Though, I am having trouble with an extremely simple thing when written in Tensorflow. Here is the tf agent code from the tutorial.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

weights = tf.Variable(tf.ones([num_bandits]))
chosen_action = tf.argmax(weights,0)

reward_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[1],dtype=tf.float32)
action_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[1],dtype=tf.int32)
responsible_weight = tf.slice(weights,action_holder,[1])
loss = -(tf.log(responsible_weight)*reward_holder)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
update = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

It's a simple multi-armed bandit. 
My work thus far in trying to convert the agent to Keras is;

```
size = 4
weights = K.variable(K.ones(shape=(size), dtype='float32'))
best_action = Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(K.argmax(x), dtype=K.floatx()))(weights)

reward = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='float32')
action = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

responsible_weight = K.slice(weights, action[-1], [1])

custom_loss = -(K.log(responsible_weight) * reward)
opti = SGD(lr=0.001)
model = Model(inputs=[reward, action], outputs=best_action)
model.compile(optimizer=opti, loss=custom_loss)
```

The challenges seem to be that Input tensors have to come from the Input layer (atleast from other exercises).

Can anyone see an obvious error here? When I get to the model=Model() line, an attributeError tells me

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

My "output" is already wrapped in a Lambda function, which in part, takes care of the Keras Tensor portion as suggested by the potential duplication. Just for fun, I added another layer and multiplied by one as the other thread suggested, but this did not change the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoneType' object has no attribute '\_inbound\_nodes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636328/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-inbound-nodes)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Keras works a little different from tensorflow in the sense that it's mandatory to have inputs (usually x_train) and outputs (usually y_train) passed as known data.

The loss in Keras must necessarily be a function that takes ground truth values and predicted (output) values: `function(y_true, y_pred)`.

By looking at your code, it seems that the loss is a [crossentropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) where **p** (y_true) is `reward` and **q** (y_pred) is `responsible_weight`.

Thus, we can remake it as if `reward` were an output (y_train or y_true) and `action_holder` an input (x_train).

```
def loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return - K.log(y_pred)*y_true
```

Also, `action_holder` is nothing but taking a single row of the weights, which fits perfectly the idea of an `Embedding` layer whose size is 1 and vocabulary is `num_bandits`.

That said, we can start modeling:

```py
#because of the log, let's also add a non negative constraint to the weights
from keras.constraints import NonNeg

input_action = Input((1,))
responsible_weight = Embedding(num_bandits, 
                               1, 
                               name='weights', 
                               embeddings_initializer='ones',
                               embeddings_constraint=NonNeg())(input_action)

model = Model(input_action, responsible_weight)
model.compile(optimizer=anyOptimizer, loss=loss)
```

For training, use:

```
model.fit(data_for_action_holder, data_for_reward, ...)
```

Input and output data must be shaped both as `(examples, 1)`

---

About the best action or chosen action, it's not participating in training at all. To get it, you will need to take the embedding weights and get its max:

```
weights = model.get_layer('weights').get_weights()[0].max()
```

About the risk of log of zero, you could slightly change the loss function to avoid zero predictions:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return - K.log(y_pred + K.epsilon())*(y_true + K.epsilon())
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I think that it will fix the problem, but am still confused about the loss function. (Actually that is the purpose of the exercises, Go back and understand how loss and reward are related in reinforcement learning).

Comment: I'll have to look at it for a while and will accept a little later.